# Pattern for preloading data for subsequent view to be displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

Very simple use case: Let's say an iOS app displays a `MovieListController` view (inside of a `UINavigationController`) with a list of movies. When the user touches on one, the app pushes a `MovieDetailController` onto the navigation stack (i.e. `[[MovieDetailController alloc] initWithMovieId:(NSString *)`. In the `MovieDetailController`'s `viewDidAppear:` method, it makes an HTTP call to retrieve details based on the movie ID passed into it.

The challenge is that the `MovieDetailController` gets pushed onto the navigation stack right away, and for a second or two while the details haven't been retrieved, the view shows a bunch of blank fields, which is undesirable.

To get around this, I'm thinking of having the `MovieListController` not push the `MovieDetailController` onto the stack right away. Instead, it would put up a progress indicator (I'm using SVProgressHUD), then call `MovieDetailController`'s `initWithMovieId:` method which would kick off the HTTP call. Then when the data is received, the `MovieDetailController` would make a callback back to `MovieListController` to remove the progress indicator and then push the `MovieDetailController` onto the navigation stack.

Is there a better pattern for this type of scenario? Should I be considering having the `MovieDetailController` push itself onto the navigation stack when it's ready?

Note: I have considered loading the detail view and putting up an activity indicator, but you'll still be able to see an 'empty view' behind it which looks a bit weird. I have also considered just having the `MovieListController` retrieve the details itself but this seems to break the encapsulation model - the `MovieListController` should just be concerned about listing movies, not about their details.

Any thoughts? This Movie stuff is just an example - looking for a general pattern here.

Comment: Seems to me the latter approach would be less desirable than waiting for the blank view to be filled in. It would give the impression the app was frozen for a few seconds. You could put placeholders up (e.g., a placeholder image for the movie) until the data is received instead of having a blank view.

Comment: I don't mind putting up an activity view on the table view while data for the detail view is being loaded. I just don't want to move to a blank detail view then display an activity view. But I'm wondering if there's some timing issues here.

Comment: You would probably get different answers at http://ux.stackexchange.com/ from UX experts for a question like this.

Comment: Fair enough @Inafziger but I'm primarily looking for the programming solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation, I personally would return to the model-view-controller pattern.

There are several system apps that display a detail view from a list of objects, e.g. Calendar, Contacts, etc. Presumably, as with `EKEvent` and `ABPerson` in their respective apps, the main view controller maintains a list of the model objects. When the user selects one of the items, the main view controller passes the selected model object to the detail view controller. The detail view controller itself doesn't have to do any data loading. So, like @ChrisWagner said, we want to separate the logic from the view controller.

### Method

Similarly, you might want to use a `MovieList` class that stores an array of `Movie` objects. Each `Movie` stores the values for all the fields in the detail view controller - essentially, all the information the app needs about the movie. For example, you might have a property `NSString *movieTitle`, or `NSDate *premiereDate`. The `movieTitle` would be set by the `MovieList` at initialization because it's just metadata; on the other hand, the `premiereDate` might be `nil` if the data hasn't loaded, so you would have a property `BOOL isLoaded` to check for this condition.

You could then proceed in one of two ways:

1) Say the main view controller wants to push a detail view controller for a movie. Then the main view controller would dig the appropriate `Movie` out of the `MovieList` and check if it's loaded. If not, it would call something like `-(void)loadContents` on the `Movie.` When the model object is finished loading, it will post a notification that it's finished loading. At this point the main view controller will dismiss its progress view and push the detail view. If you use (1), it's not as important to use a `MovieList` coordinator.

2) If you want to be more aggressive about loading the movie information, you could implement a method on `MovieList` that calls `loadContents` on its `Movie`s in the background. Then there's a higher chance that a movie will already be loaded when the user selects it.

**Edit**: Note that if you decide to use a `MovieList` type object, only the main view controller should be allowed to access this list. In a way, the model structure I've described parallels the view controller structure. The detail view controller doesn't know about the list view controller, so it shouldn't know about the `MovieList` either.

### Benefit

The benefit of using this `Movie` and `MovieList` structure is that the data model is *completely separated* from the view controllers. That way, the user is free to cancel, select, present and dismiss view controllers while the data is loading. (Imagine if the user pressed Back to dismiss the progress HUD, canceling any HTTP data it would have gathered. *Then, if he decides to come back to that same movie, the new detail view controller has to start loading afresh.*) Also, if you decide to replace view controller classes in the development process, you won't have to copy and paste a bunch of data-handling code.

I think you'll find that structuring your app in this way not only gives you and the user more freedom, it also makes your app efficient and open to later extensions. (Sorry to post so late, but I wanted to include MVC in this pattern-related discussion!)

Comment: I like the idea of #2, you could start fetching the movie data for the items that are visible in the list, to predict that the user will want to view their details. If it is just textual data it shouldn't be too heavy to make the requests. The Apple movie trailer app does this for thumbnails on each cell, as you scroll it sends off requests for the thumbnail to display.

Comment: Exactly. And the great thing is that you have fine control over how you handle the loading. You may decide to show a blank detail view (or, what I would do is hide all the views leaving just a solid color background) and show the HUD there, or you may choose to show it on the main view. It's much easier to change the behavior if you isolate the data from the view controllers.

Comment: It sounds like the Model-View-Controller-Store pattern. I've actually already got something like this. The data model and retrieval logic is separated into a MovieStore object. My concern with this question is moreso who and when that MovieStore should be invoked? i.e. is the list controller or the detail controller that should call it to retrieve the Movie object?

Comment: See my edited answer. The detail controller should not be able to retrieve movies from the MovieStore because that would violate its purpose: to view information about a particular movie.

Comment: Ah ok, that's interesting. That makes sense that the MovieDetail controller shouldn't have to know about the MovieListController but it's ok for the MovieListController to know about the MovieDetail. Sounds like you're saying that in this case the MovieListController is really driving the use case and thus it should own all interaction with the "store" object (MovieList in your example). Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Can you elaborate about this concept of a "main view controller" @architectpianist? One complication is when the VC hierarchy is nested fairly deep - which in my case it is (the MovieList -> MovieDetail is just a simplified example).  What if it's several levels deep (eg: MovieViewController -> MovieDetailsController -> MovieActorListController -> MovieActorController -> MovieActorPicturesController). Are you saying only MovieController would talk to the store? How would it feed data down deep into the view controller stack?

Comment: To your first question: yes, the top level of the navigation stack should manage the top level of the store structure. As to your second question, here the waters get murkier. When you add a second type of model object, you have to handle the interaction between the two. In this case, you might have a single `[MovieList masterList]` that stored all the movies, and the view controllers down the hierarchy would be able to query it for actors in a movie, movies for an actor, etc. So when the *direction of information flow* changes, you have to change the model structure to match.

Answer (score 5):

Personally I would take the following approach.

1. User selects the movie they want details for
2. Push to the detail view and rather than showing your skeleton view with empty fields, overlay a loading view, you could continue using your progress HUD on top of this for any animations you gain with that.
3. Once the results come down, remove your HUD and the loading overlay view that is hiding all the data/fields

The reason I would go this route rather than showing the HUD before pushing the view controller is that you can give the user the opportunity to cancel their selection. I am not familiar with `SVProgressHUD` but hopefully when a HUD is displayed you can enable touches, specifically the user touching Back on your `UINavigationController` in the event they accidentally selected the movie or the request is just taking longer than they are willing to wait for.

It also separates the logic form your list view, your detail view is standalone and could be initialized anywhere in your app (maybe you want to cross link similar movies within a movie detail view) and you do not need to rewrite the logic of the presenting view waiting on the results to come back.

Comment: Yes, separating the logic from the list view is what I would like to do and your solution does that. Also good point about cancelling, I hadn't even thought of that, I will take this under consideration now. What did you have in mind though for an overlay? Could you give me a hint as to how/when it would be created/displayed/hidden? Also were you just thinking of a "Please wait" sort of thing visually?

Comment: That is what I was thinking, something to indicate that this view is going to be replaced with content once it loads. As far as how to show /hide the view... I would just create a UIView (maybe a UIImageView depending on how you want to style it) and `[self.view addSubView:_overlayView]; [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_overlayView];` Then I would just `[_overlayView removeFromSuperview];` when the results come back... I would probably throw in some animations, maybe fade it out before removing it from the superview.

Comment: Ok, thanks - I like it. I'll give it another day or so to see if anybody wants to chime in with anything else unique from this.

Answer (score 1):

I think a more advanced route would be to start the detail requests as the cells are being being shown on  in the tableview/collection view. Then as the cells move offscreen, cancel the requests. You might be loading movie details unnecessarily, but I don't think this is a big deal, because you'd only be filling your db with movie details you might not need and coredata can handle that. This is assuming that your api requests are happening on a bg thread and they don't affect the main(UI) thread.